# embed swf with action script 3 in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I'm very new in flash and flex and my first task is to be able to embed an SWF made in adobe cs4 using actionscript 3... the problem is I'm not able to embed it in Flex, it is weird though that if for example i add a sound to the swf file to be embedded in flash i'm able to hear the sound but it is not showing up (not visible) in the flex generated swf file

One other thing is if i try to set the flash swf to be embedded to use actionscript 2 then it gets shown in the flex generated swf but if i really need to be able to use actionscript 3 so no use for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the answer, i was able to figure it our after some time, it really doesn't matter if i use an image or swfloader to load the embedded swf, the problem is i cannot really directly call a function of the embedded SWF from the embedding SWF, what i had to do was dispatch events so that flex can communicate with flash and vice versa,,, this page was very useful for me http://flash.fincanon.com/archives/152

Answer (score 0):

What is your code for embedding it ?

I suggest you to take a look at SWFLoader. Here is some code and samples:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_15.html